# Small React todo app

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a small todo app where you can add and mark todos as completed. I structured it that all the data is kept in the parent container (`TodoWrapper`), that renders 2 components which are the toDo list and the createTodo component. I see others who are having state inside the `createTodo` component wonder if that is good practice or keeping it in parent and only invoking the event handler from child. I also left some questions inside the code to explain better. I know it's not just a few lines of code, but I would really appreciate so much if I get some feedback because Im trying to improve!

```
class TodoWrapper extends React.Component {
    state = {
        todos: [],
        currentItem: {text: "", id: "", checked: false}
    };

    onChange = (input, check) => {
        this.setState({
            currentItem: {
                text: input,
                id: Date.now() / Math.random(),
                checked: false
            }
        })
    };

    addItem = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const newItem = this.state.currentItem
        if (newItem.text !== '') {

            const todos = [...this.state.todos, newItem]

            this.setState({
                todos: todos,
                currentItem: { text: '', id: '', checked: false },
            })
        }
    };

// please see below I have implemented handleCheck differently

    handleCheck = (isChecked, id) => {
        const filteredItems = this.state.todos.map(item => {
           if (item.id === id) {
               return {...item, ["checked"]: isChecked}
           } else {
               return {...item};
           }
        });
        this.setState({
            todos: filteredItems,
        })
    };

//below function (which i do not use)is faster since its only look up but is it better since I only rely on index? 

//Also, since I have an array with nested objects - did I directly mutate,since I only have shallow copy?

//Thus, is it better to iterate (which is slower, but not directly mutate state which I believe I did not in first example of handleCheck function)

(
    handleCheck = (index) => {
        const newTodos = [...this.state.todos];
        newTodos[index].checked =!newTodos[index].checked;
        this.setState({
            todos: newTodos,
        })
    };
)
    render () {
        console.log("render todos", this.state.todos)
        return (
            <div className="todo-container">
                <CreateTodo
                    addItem={this.addItem}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    currentItem={this.currentItem}
                />
                <TodoList
                    todos={this.state.todos}
                    handleCheck={this.handleCheck}
                />
            </div>    
        )
    }
}

const TodoList = ({todos, handleCheck}) => {
   const renderList = todos.map((item, index) => {
       const checkedOf = item.checked ? "checked" : "";
            return (
                <TodoItem
                    id={item.id}
                    index={index}
                    key={item.id}
                    style={checkedOf}
                    text={item.text}
                    checked={item.isChecked}
                    handleCheck={handleCheck}
               />
            )
        });

        return (
            <ul className="list">
                {renderList}
            </ul>
        )
    };

const TodoItem = ({style, id, index, text, checked, handleCheck}) => {
    return (
        <li className={`item_text ${style}`}>
            {text}
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={checked}
                onClick={({target})=> handleCheck(target.checked, id, index)}
            />
        </li>
    )
};

const CreateTodo = ({addItem, currentItem, onChange}) => {

//When does it make sense to have state inside the component with the input?

//I passed from parent the onChange function, that I invoke here and SEND BACK the value ONLY to receive BACK the value which doesnt seem to make sense to me.

//On the other hand it makes sense to keep state in the parent.

    const onInputChange = (event) => {
        onChange(event.target.value)
    };
    return (
        <form className="submit_task_form" onSubmit={addItem}>
            <input className="submit_task_form__input" value={currentItem} onChange={onInputChange}/>
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
    )
};
```

Comment: The multiple versions of some functions make the post confusing IMO. Consider editing your question to make it clearer what code you're actually using - you can even add an executable "stack snippet" (hit Ctrl+M when editing) to showcase & demonstrate your app. I find the "//" notes confusing, too: they look like they're in-code comments but read like they're part of the body

Comment: I don't see why TodoWrapper needs to know when you edit the Todo unless you are going to let the user edit previous Todos so you need to know which one is being edited. The way it is right now, I would only call addItem() and pass as a parameter the current todo that CreateTodo would have on its state. In other words, the only time TodoWrapper uses the current todo is when addItem gets called, but this could get called with the todo as a parameter coming from CreateTodo.